# How to define the intersection of two lines as a point

Tags: geometry, synthetic-geometry

I tried the code below (I sort of translated it from written notation), where I hoped that [Intersection] would give me the intersection of line ac with the altitude from b:

```
scene1 = 
  GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d}, 
    {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
    d ∈ {Line[{a, c}] ⋂ 
      TriangleConstruct[{a, b, c}, "Altitude"]}, 
      TriangleConstruct[{a, c, b}, "Altitude"]}];
RandomInstance[scene1, 3]
```

It did not work. How do I then define the intersection of two lines as a point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the intersection of two line, it is recommend that use `{Line[{a,x,c}],Line[{b,x,d}]}` or `{InfiniteLine[{a, x, c}], InfiniteLine[{b, x, d}]}` etc.

```
Clear["`*"];
RandomInstance@
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, x}, {InfiniteLine[{a, x, c}], 
   InfiniteLine[{b, x, d}]}]
```

If you want to get the `Foot` of `Altitude`,maybe you can try the following approach.

```
GeometricScene[{a, b, c, 
   d -> TriangleConstruct[{a, b, c}, {"Foot", b}]}, {Line[{a, c}], 
   Line[{b, d}]}]~RandomInstance~3
```

[image]

Comment: What is ~ supposed to mean and how is it used? It only says 'Infix' in the Wolfram Documentation.

Comment: @Cheng   `a~f~b` just as `f[a,b]`